# I want to mass edit hundreds of files by changing just one character in a particular spot

Tags: regex

I want to mass edit a bunch of .ent files from a game. What I want to do is simply have a program that goes through every file and look for a pattern. That pattern is a directory. Here's an example:

```
array:raRef:CResource�base\characters\garment\citizen_casual\legs\l0_004_tights__fishnet\l0_004_wa_tights__fishnet_prostitute.mesh
```

I want to change this part:

```
l0_004_wa_tights__fishnet_prostitute.mesh
```

To this:

```
.0_004_wa_tights__fishnet_prostitute.mesh
```

A dot at the beginning of the filename represented as 00 in hex. So basically I need a program that finds the pattern of a directory with the backslashes \ and then when it encounters the last backslash, the character after it gets replaced with the 00 hex value.

Is this doable? There are sometimes multiple directories in each file and sometimes the filenames end in .mesh or .app

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
(\\[^\\])(?=[^\\]+\.[\w]+)
```

and replace it by this:

```
\\.
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OVRQ0l/1)

Explanation:

1. `(\\[^\\])` - match a backslash followed by a not back slash character
2. `(?=[^\\]+\.[\w]+)` - positive lookahead `?=` to check if there are
   characters with no backslash and which is followed by a dot . with
   one or more character as extension `\w+`

Comment: Thanks! What program do you recommend to mass edit files with this regex?

Comment: I found a tool and it worked great called TextCrawler: https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawler.html  Replaced 8000 instances in seconds.